# Validating Oracle dates in Python

Tags: python, oracle, validation

Our Python CMS stores some date values in a generic "attribute" table's *varchar* column.  Some of these dates are later moved into a table with an actual *date* column.  If the CMS user entered an invalid date, it doesn't get caught until the migration, when the query fails with an "Invalid string date" error.

How can I use Python to make sure that all dates put into our CMS are valid Oracle string date representations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I use Python to make sure that all dates put into our CMS are valid Oracle string date representations?

I'd change the approach a bit. Have Python parse the original date input as forgivingly as possible, then output the date in a known-good representation.

[dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)'s liberal parser may be a good place to start:

```
import dateutil.parser
d= dateutil.parser.parse('1/2/2003')
d.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
```

I'm not sure '%d-%b-%y' is actually still the right date format for Oracle, but it'll probably be something similar, ideally with four-digit years and no reliance on month names. (Trap: %b is locale-dependent so may return unwanted month names on a non-English OS.) Perhaps “strftime('%Y-%m-%d')” followed by “TO_DATE(..., 'YYYY-MM-DD')” at the Oracle end is needed?

Comment: I'd use '%d-%b-%Y' (4 digit years), but you're right about the locale dependency. +1 for suggesting a great approach.

Answer (score 1):

The format of a date string that Oracle recognizes as a date is a configurable property of the database and as such it's considered bad form to rely on implicit conversions of strings to dates.

Typically Oracle dates format to 'DD-MON-YYYY' but you can't always rely on it being set that way.

Personally I would have the CMS write to this "attribute" table in a standard format like 'YYYY-MM-DD', and then whichever job moves that to a DATE column can explicitly cast the value with to_date( value, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) and you won't have any problems.

Answer (score -1):

Validate as early as possible. Why don't you store dates as dates in your Python CMS?

It is difficult to know what date a string like '03-04-2008' is. Is it 3 april 2008 or 4 march 2008? An American will say 4 march 2008 but a Dutch person will say 3 april 2008.